# Find boolean function

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

Given

$\mathbb{B} = \{true, false\}$,

and function $f: \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{B},  f(a,b,c) = a \land b \lor c,~ \forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{B}$.

I want to find a function $g: \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \times \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{B}$ such that $g(a,b,c,\neg a, \neg b, \neg c) = \neg f(a,b,c) ~\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{B}$.

A significant constraint is that $g$ may *only* use function $f$ (with parameters $a,b,c,\neg a, \neg b, \neg c$), constants $true$ and $false$, logical conjunction ($\land$) and disjunction ($\lor$). In particular, negation ($\neg$) and input parameters $a,b,c,\neg a, \neg b, \neg c$ must **not** be used (directly).

Is there any systematic way to find such a function $g$? How can I know whether such a function exists at all?

Sorry for the bad title of this question. I didn't know better.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to determine whether such function exists, and if yes - then it is also a way to construct the function. It's called *Truth Table*.

Comment: By De Morgan's law, $\overline{a\land b\lor c}=\overline a\lor\overline b\land\overline c$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, aren't you missing crucial parentheses?

Comment: @Florian: just complying to the OP's style.

Comment: I probably did not make this requirement clear enough: $g$ must also not directly use $a,b,c,\neg a, \neg b, \neg c$, but only $f$ (with parameters $a,b,c,\neg a, \neg b, \neg c$), $\land$, and $\lor$.

Comment: Try $g(a,b,c,\neg a,\neg b,\neg c):=f(a,b,\neg c)\land f(\neg a,\neg a,\neg b)$.